# How to convert string to a class object name

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get an object to use from a string. How can I do that? the program should get the selected combobox's text and search data with it in MongoDB.

```
string parameter = cmbSearch.Text;
var results = collection.AsQueryable().Where(b => b.parameter.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text));
```

It should look like this I guess. b.parameter substitution for b.Author or b.Title...

Here is my Books class:

```
class Books
{
    [BsonId]
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Editor { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Year { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public int No { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string PageSetup { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string OriginalLanguage { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Translator { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string OriginalName { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of  `collection`? is that `b.parameter` a pseudo-code? How are combobox or mongoDB relevant to your problem?

Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: b.parameter is a pseudo-code. It should represent what is selected in combobox. in example: if combobox's text is Author b.parameter represent b.Author, but i just can select one of Books properties(like author,title,isbn etc.). 
I wanna do full search in all fields with just one textbox in mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) should help.

Try to use it like this:

```
Type elementType = Type.GetType(cmbSearch.Text); //Be careful here if elementType is null. You must provide it like this: Type.GetType("MyProject.Domain.Model." + myClassName + ", AssemblyName");

dynamic dO = Activator.CreateInstance(elementType);
```

You can find sample code on [rextester](http://rextester.com/KBHS47811).

Comment: it has an error: value cannot be null. elementType is null. You can find better expression in question's comments

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be resolved by **reflection**  - an API included in .Net FW that you can use to work with metadata of your classes during runtime. For example to get names of all properties or to get/set a value on any of them. [Read more about it from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example code to initialize combobox with valid values:

```
var properties = typeof(Book).GetProperties();
List<String> comboboxValues = properties.Select(property => property.Name).ToList();
```

After user has given input:

```
String searchBy = "Author";
String searchValue = "Isaac Asimov";

List<Book> booksFromMongo = new List<Book>(); //TODO: Query mongo.

PropertyInfo searchByProperty = typeof(Book).GetProperty(searchBy);
List<Book> matches = booksFromMongo
    .Where(book => (String) searchByProperty.GetValue(book) == searchValue)
    .ToList();
```

Obviously you need to do more tricks to validate input, handle different types in comparion, etc, but this should get you started.